# Flot zoom broken with latest version of jQuery?

Tags: jquery, charts, flot

The Flot zooming seems to be broken with the latest version of jQuery. Zooming in causes the chart to be emptied and blank.

Is there any workaround for this?

Comment: What version of Flot are you using?  This sounds like something we fixed in master.

Comment: I am using flot 0.7 downloaded directly from the website.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is fixed in [master](https://github.com/flot/flot/zipball/master).  Your options are to either use that, revert to an earlier version of jQuery, or back-port the fix into your local 0.7 until the final release of 0.8.

Comment: Where can we find the information about back-porting the fix?

Comment: It's spread across a few commits, but your best bet is simply to update the inline minified mousewheel plugin to the latest version; that accounted for the majority of problems.